# Is there a way to make dynamic custom tick marks in Flutters SliderTheme widget?

Tags: flutter, slider

I have been working with flutters Slider widget and been customizing my own SliderTickMarkShape for the SliderTheme. But I want each of the TickMarkers to display the current number. For example i want it to show the numbers below. 1 to 7, where the sliderthumb is set of number four. However, the SliderTickMarkShape can only cannot have variables. This makes me only able to have the same number for all slidertickmarks. Is there a way to make dynamic tick marks? So that each individual tick mark kan be unique, with for example showing another number.

1 2 3 (4) 5 6 7

Answer (score 0):

There are good articles and screencasts on how to use a CustomPaint to build a slider precisely as you wish, and it's not that hard either. :)

Here's one of my favorites... from a well-known screencaster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC3sL5SmizM.